# Is it possible to get other collection than IEnumerable<T> when using LINQ: XML to object?

Tags: c#, linq, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

So I have this huge XML file that I am converting to an object by using LINQ. And currently I am doing:

```
var resultStories = from story in resultXML.Descendants("story")
                    select new NewsStory
                    {
                        ArticleFrequency = from tag in story.Descendants("tag")
                                           select new KeyValuePair<string,int>((string)tag.Element("name"),(int)tag.Element("count"))
                    };
```

Now this gives creates a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String,int>>` for me. But I am wondering if it is possible to get another collection such as a `Dictionary<String,int>` or `List<new MyItem(string key, int value)` ?

I have this huge LINQ book and it only contains information about Objects to XML.
This question pertains XML to Objects.

Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the extension methods available, there are ToDictionary, ToArray, and ToList (I may or may not be missing one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible using Linqs [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx) method.

You should be able to say

```
ArticleFrequency = (from tag in story.Descendants("tag")
                    select new
                    { 
                        Key = (string)tag.Element("name"),
                        Value = (int)tag.Element("count")
                    }).ToDictionary(val => val.Key, val => val.Value)
```

Your `ArticleFrequency` property will of course need to be of type `IDictionary<string, int>`

**UPDATE** To answer your question in the comments (if I understand correctly), just change the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) to return an Enumerable of the desired type e.g.

```
ArticleFrequency = (from tag in story.Descendants("tag")
                    select new MyCustomObject()
                    { 
                        MyPropertyOne = (string)tag.Element("name"),
                        MyPropertyTwo = (int)tag.Element("count")
                    })
```

will assign an `IEnumerable<MyCustomObject>` to ArticleFrequency. If you are saying you want ArticleFrequency to be of type Stack you can just wrap the whole Linq query and use it as the IEnumerable parameter to the [Stack constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack_members.aspx) e.g.

```
ArticleFrequency = new Stack<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(
                        (from tag in story.Descendants("tag")
                        select new KeyValuePair<string, int>()
                        { 
                            Key = (string)tag.Element("name"),
                            Value = (int)tag.Element("count")
                        }))
```

Comment: I didn't know that! THanks :D But is there asyntax to turn it into any class that i might have defined within a collection that might be anything from a Stack, List, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it to return a Dictionary like so:

```
ArticleFrequency = story.Descendants("tag").ToDictionary<XElement, string,int>()(
    tag=>(string)tag.Element("name"),
    tag=>(int)tag.Element("count")
);
```

Comment: I didn't know that! THanks :D But is there asyntax to turn it into any class that i might have defined within a collection that might be anything from a Stack, List, etc?